Converting LaTeX to HTML without losing formatting from titlesec & titling
I've tried several existing TeX->HTML solutions, including tex4ht, pandoc, and lwarp, but all suffer from a similar issue where they completely lose all formatting done by titlesec, geometry, titling, etc.
Here's what I expect things to look like:


Here are various results from the different programs I've tried.


Note the lack of scshape, the presence of the author, lack of the titlerule and frame, and large margins.

Notice the lack of linebreak between title & date, no title formatting at all (just the default), and large margins.
For reference, here's the relevant section of my TeX file.
\documentclass{article}

% Geo & Spacing
\usepackage{setspace}
\doublespacing

\usepackage{geometry}[margin=1in]

% Title formatting
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titling}

\titleformat{\section}{\huge\scshape}{}{1.5em}{}[\titlerule]

\titleformat{\subsection}{\Large\bfseries}{}{1em}{}
\titlespacing{\subsection}{1em}{0.5em}{0.75em}

\titleformat{\subsubsection}[frame]{\large\itshape}{}{0.75em}{}

\title{I Went to Kenya}
\author{author}
\date{\today}

\renewcommand{\maketitle}{
    \begin{center}
        {\Huge \bfseries \thetitle}

        \vspace{20pt}

        {\large Updated \thedate}
    \end{center}
}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

\subsection{Preface}

\indent Kenya is not, and may never be, as advanced or developed as many ``Western'' countries. The point of this paper is not to turn the West into the likes of Kenya, rather it is to educate about Kenya \& Maasai culture and what we can learn from it.

\subsubsection{Let's not forget, though}

\end{document}



The structure of the text is preserved but not the layout? That's good news. It is not always possible, easy or convenient to maintain the appearance of everything in the document in other format, and when conversion tools attempt to do so, the result is often disastrous, leaving the text riddled with dirty code that is much more complicated to clean up than make the document from the scratch.  Better a clean HTML with readable tags and that can be edited or redesigned at CSS level with low pain.

All converters try to produce clean HTML with semantic markup. Replicating of the exact visual style as in the PDF is not something that could be easily done automatically. It is best to leave it to the author, who can use CSS to change the document appearance.
For example with TeX4ht, you can use the following configuration file to fix two issues: your redefinition of \maketitle, which loses the default semantic markup used by TeX4ht to markup titles, and styling of the sectioning commands:
% the nostyle option will remove default page margins
\Preamble{xhtml,nostyle}

% remove section numbers
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}

% format \maketitle
\renewcommand{\maketitle}{
  \ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\HCode{<div class="maketitle">\Hnewline}
  \HCode{<h1 class="title">}\thetitle\HCode{</h1>\Hnewline}
  \HCode{<div class="updated">}{\large Updated \thedate}\HCode{</div>}
  \ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\HCode{</div>}
}

% change appearance of title and sections
\Css{.maketitle{text-align: center;}}
\Css{h1.title{font-size:3rem;}}
\Css{.sectionHead{font-weight: normal; border-bottom: 1px solid black; font-size: 1.7rem;font-variant: small-caps}}
\Css{.subsectionHead{font-size:1.3rem;}}
\Css{.subsubsectionHead{font-weight: normal;border: 1px solid black; font-size:1.2rem;}}

\begin{document}
\EndPreamble

You can compile your document using:
 $ make4ht -c config.cfg sample.tex

This is the result:


+1 Very nice, as always
